# How to create notifications that will notify person in the right time even if app is closed

Tags: android, notifications, foreground

I am making an app where people will type their jobs and tasks for that day, and then throught the day app will notify them. What should I use. Should I use something like JobScheduler or something like Foreground service. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can approach to your issue at least on two ways.

First way is to implement `AlarmManager` which is going to start service which is going to check is new message arrived and if it is you can rise notification. But some limitations of this approach are that you have to setup `AlaramManager` to trigger services once a while for example each 15 min and if in meanwhile message arrives user will not be notified in realtime.

Second approach is to use some third part client like `FCM` which is free but with limitation to 4kb per message(notification message) which is actualy pretty enough for notification.

AlarmManager Doc : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

FCM Doc : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client